# How do I fix this weird entity framework error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Got this error message while trying to configure an entitydatasource in the designer:

[image]

My .edmx file is in a class library in the same solution.  I added the necessary DLL's and copied the connection to the web.config.  The weird part is that I can query the database, and get data just fine, so I know my connection string is correct.  Has anybody come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this steps:

Rebuild your solution

Go to your class library app.config

Copy the connectionstring of your created EDMx and paste it to

web.config connectionstring section of your asp.net project ..

I also got this error before and this is what i did.

If this does not work try to delete your edmx file(and its connectionstring on app.config)  and recreate it. Then follow the above steps again.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Can you delete and recreate the edmx file? This will fix things (although this is a blunt measure).

Comment: I suppose I could.  Just the edmx file, or all the entity files that go along with it?

Comment: Purge everything. The build process will recreate everything from the edmx. Note, that this only works, if you have little or no modifications in the edmx (which is what I recommend).